# how to get accurate distance from Location listener in android

Tags: android

i am new android development i am trying to build a GPS based tracking system where our customer will pay to my client based on KMS calculation but i am not to get accurate distance i tried with distanceTo method and Distancebetween none of them giving accurate results can someone pls help me on this

```
if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                /*if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return null;
                }*/
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
```

from this i am getting LatLng and using onLocationChanged method i am taking new Location and calculating distance using distance To can you please suggest us best way even i tried with

```
 public static double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2,
                              double lon2, char unit) {
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    Log.d("Distance","from distance"+dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    if (unit == 'K') {
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
        Log.d("Distance","from distance after unit"+dist);
    } else if (unit == 'N') {
        dist = dist * 0.8684;
    }
    return (dist);
}
```

Comment: // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 50; // 50 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000*60*3;// 3 minute

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Location  locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(currentLati);
    locationA.setLongitude(currentLongi);

Location locationB = new Location("point B");
                    locationB.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(destinationLatitude));
                    locationB.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(destinationLongitude));
                    //float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB); //in metres
                    float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB)/1000; //in KM
```

Comment: i tried even distanceTo and Distance Between also but i am  getting distance but not accurate if i travel for 10kms i am getting 7.5kms

Comment: actually it is returning the shortest distance between points to get list of possible distance between 2 points use  distanceBetween method   check out this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])

Answer (score 0):

To get the best location use this function:

```
public static LocationManager mLocationManager;

 private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        try {
            for (String provider : providers) {
                Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                if (l == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                    // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                    bestLocation = l;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return bestLocation;
    }
```